# LVM Snapshot mapping into new logical volume that's bigger

Tags: backup, lvm

If I create a snapshot say:

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name homeSnap /dev/vg1/home
```

then i back up this snapshot:

```
dd if=/dev/vg1/homeSnap of=/mnt/data/backup.img
```

then create a new logical volume

```
lvcreate --size 50G --name test vg1
```

then copy the snapshot to the new logical drive:

```
dd if=/mnt/data/backup.img of=/dev/vg1/test
```

Now say that the original /dev/vg1/home is only 10G size. The /dev/vg1/test is 50G. What happens to the other 40G will i be able to use this as normal or does the new /dev/vg1/test only become 10G and I lose the 40G without some type of resizing?

Comment: Have you try to extend the filesystem?

Comment: Hi Romeo, no I haven't done that. Actually I haven't tried this yet but I'm about to. I'm using xfs so do I need to extend the filesystem afterwards? or I won't get the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It of course depends on whatever you have on the `/dev/vg1/homeSnap` volume.  But most filesystems will not automatically resize, you must issue a command to resize the filesystem.

In a comment you mentioned XFS, the command you want is [xfs_growfs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsgrow.html), I believe maybe `xfs_growfs /dev/vg1/test` in your situation.

One other thing you might need to watch out for is that some filesystems  have a unique ID, and if you try to mount two copies of the filesystem that have the same unique ID you can have problems.  I am not sure about the current state, but in the past [XFS required special steps](http://www.miljan.org/main/2009/11/16/lvm-snapshots-and-xfs/) like generating a new ID, or passing a mount option to ignore the ID.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache, you're correct xfs didn't let me mount the same snapshot volume if the other was already mounted because of the unique ID... But actually it doesn't matter because i'm doing this for backup purposes and would only mount if the first gets corrupted. Cheers